# Rails 5.2 - Purge all Active Storage Attachments via Rake through docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rails-activestorage

First question after years of trying not bothering anyone but really need help.  I built a Dockerized Rails 5.2 Active Storage/Postgers content management system that uses a rake data pipeline to ingest a set of csv files for building the core models.  The final step is to download and attach images to the Entity model:

```
     has_one_attached :mark
```

As I receive a new set of csv files from my client, I have a process where I manually move the new files into a work-in-process folder, delete all of the files in storage/, stop all of the containers running the app, database, and server, then run a suite of rake tasks that starts with resetting and migrating the database:

```
    docker-compose run --rm app rake db:migrate:reset
```

then runs two sets of tasks, one that loads all of the records for each model from the csv and the next that links all of the records to one another.  As noted, the final step was to attach the images.  However, even before I attach the images again, I test that the system works WITHOUT any images.  Note, I have manually deleted everything in storage/, I've dropped the database, migrated it, loaded all of the data EXCEPT the images, reload a page and I get this error:

```
    variant delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil
```

and when I inspect entity.mark I get this:

```
Mark: [#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x000055e485721fb8 @name="mark", @record=#<Entity id: 2, name: " Huashan Hospital", slug: "huashan_hospital", imageurl: "https://dl.airtable.com/OE7WXy0jRTe7zdFb79Fj_hsyy....", created_at: "2018-07-20 22:25:58", updated_at: "2018-07-20 22:25:58">, @dependent=:purge_later>
```

Which has me begging the question, where is this coming from?  There are NO entries in Postgres for

```
select * from active_storage_attachments;
id | name | record_type | record_id | blob_id | created_at 
----+------+-------------+-----------+---------+------------
(0 rows)
```

or in

```
select * from active_storage_blobs;
 id | key | filename | content_type | metadata | byte_size | checksum | created_at 
----+-----+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+----------+------------
(0 rows)
```

and there are no files in storage/

```
ls -la storage/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 bauer  staff   136 Jul 20 15:34 .
drwxr-xr-x  36 bauer  staff  1224 Jul 18 21:11 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 bauer  staff  6148 Jul 20 15:34 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 bauer  staff     0 May  8 21:20 .keep
```

I suspect my problem is not understanding in depth how ActiveStorage works, specifically purge vs purge_later, how Docker affects Rails development, my boorish behavior of brute-force manual deletion of storage/ and the resetting of the database, the shocking hubris I've displayed in thinking I could just learn Rails 5.2, ActiveStorage, and Dockerization all at once.

Most humbly, I beseech.

Answer (score 1):

`Entity#mark` always returns an `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` object, even when no mark is attached. This facilitates the `entity.mark.attach(...)` API.

Call [`ActiveStorage::Attached::One#attached?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html#method-i-attached-3F) to determine whether a mark is attached:

```
<% if entity.mark.attached? %>
  <%= image_tag entity.mark.variant(...) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Bless you, George.  I had been testing for existence, not attachment.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm still having issues.  Things worked fine for a while, and then all of a sudden I get another random error under different conditions with the error  "Nil location provided. Can't build URI."  I seem to be fundamentally missing something about how ActiveStorage works or how the whole framework for something like ActiveStorage works overall.  I'm just trying to load some images and resize them locally.